# Node JS Deploying API to client without any Front End

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, backend

If i created api in nodejs like login,registration,delete,add,update user like system and i want to give it to my client how can i deploy it??
Like we run our API's on POstman so how client will use it! I don't want to add any front End to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few options... you can go for heroku or a virtual private server. For vps you have options like aws ec2, google cloud platform etc. You can host your app in a vps with a static ip. You can use pm2 to host the app. Https is better. Use an nginx reverse proxy for security. Proffesional api servers do the above...